# Cannot reload AVD list: /Users/adilmalik/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_21_x86.avd/config.ini (Permission denied

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

When I go to Run/Debug Configuration of my project, I keep getting this error.

[image]

If I click OK, the error comes again and it keeps coming. I cannot do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `Android Studio` as an `Administrator`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by deleting the folder that the error message refers to. (Actually, I unplugged the device, deleted the folder, and then plugged the device back in. I'm not sure whether it was necessary to unplug the device.)